# How to track the progress of command executed using Start command

Tags: command-line, command, command-line-interface, teamcity, command-prompt

Consider an command which has to be executed more than once at the same time, I have created a bat file in which Start command is used to execute the command multiple times at once. But there are couple of problem I am facing,

1. After starting all the commands the main batch file is closed. It is not waiting until the new command window has done its job.
2. We are not able to keep track of the progress in new windows, for example consider the commands are executed from team city(CI) then the progress is not tracked.

Please help me on this, Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

1) - Use `START "" /WAIT`, than start command wait till started process terminate, than continue running batch file.